# solving exponential function with linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the solutions to x for below equation.

For, $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^a(bx+c) = d$.

Is it possible to express the solution of $x$ with $a,b,c,d$ for this equation? If possible, how can I find it?

Comment: Even when $a$ is a positive integer you cannot solve it explicitly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy then, is there any way to get an approximated solution of $x$?

Comment: Only a numerical method would work. This is not an equation that would yield a closed form solution.

Comment: Numerical schemes could be regula falsi or newton's method. However to which solution the scheme converges (and if it converges at all) is highly dependent on the starting values and the explicit values of $a,b,c,d$. Especially the value of $a$ is crucial for the behaviour.